# simulator reports wrong Bundle number

Tags: ios, xcode

in our iOS application, I display the bundle number in a settings menu. I retrieve the bundle number like this:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]];
```

the strange thing is, that it reports an old number (1.0.3) although the target settings (for device) in XCode are set to 1.0.6 for both, version and build. I do not know how to set these numbers for the simulator target, there don't seem to be options for these when switching to simulator target.

On the device the proper version is displayed.

what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Obvious questions first: did you reset the simulator? Did you do a clean build before you ran it on the simulator?

Comment: yes I choose product->clean first (several times)